# Python tkinter Variables not defined

Tags: python, tkinter

Advanced baseball metrics calculator. I had it working late one night, forgot to save, now I'm dumbfounded. I keep getting "E1 / E2 / E3 not defined" Any guidance as to what I'm doing wrong will be greatly appreciated.

I'm sure it's something simple

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox 

    
def pythagentry():
    pythaginput = Tk()
    L0 = Label(pythaginput, text= "Expected Wins", fg="black", font = "Times")
    L0.grid(row=1, column=1)
    L1 = Label(pythaginput, text= "Runs Scored", fg="black", font= "Times")
    L1.grid(row=2, column=1)
    L2 = Label(pythaginput, text= "Runs Allowed", fg="black", font= "Times")
    L2.grid(row=3, column=1)
    L3 = Label(pythaginput, text= "Season Length", fg="black", font= "Times")
    L3.grid(row=4, column=1)
    RS = Entry(pythaginput,bd=5)
    RS.grid (row=2, column=2)
    E2 = Entry(pythaginput,bd=5)
    E2.grid (row=3, column=2)
    E3 = Entry(pythaginput,bd=5)
    E3.grid (row=4, column=2)
    B4 = Button (pythaginput,text='Calculate Pythagorean Wins', command = pythag )
    B4.grid (row=5, column=2)

    
def pythag():
    pythagoutput = Tk()
    L4=Label(pythagoutput,text="Expected Wins:",fg="red")
    L4.grid (row =1, column =1)
    E5=Entry(pythagoutput,bd=5)
    E5.grid(row=4,column=1)
    runsscored= float(E1.get())
    runsallowed= float(E2.get())
    lengthseason= float(E3.get())
    ratio = runsscored / runsallowed
    winpct = pow (ratio, 2) / (pow(ratio, 2) + 1)
    expectedwins = lengthseason * winpct
    E5.insert(expectedwins)
    E5['bg']='grey'
    
  

    

top = Tk()
B1=Button(top, text='Calculate Pythagorean Wins',command = pythagentry,bg="blue")
B1.grid(row=1,column=1)

B2=Button(top, text='Calculate wOBA', bg="Blue")
B2.grid(row=1, column=2)

B3=Button(top, text='Calculate RF/9', bg="blue")
B3.grid(row=2, column=1)




top.mainloop()
```

Comment: `E2` and `E3` are local variables inside the `pythagentry()` function.  They are not visible outside of that function.  And I don't see `E1` defined anywhere.

Comment: Think John Gordon's comment is on the right track. Suggest taking a bit of time to go over how variable scope works in python to save yourself future pain: https://pythonbasics.org/scope/

Comment: I thought that the issue might be the variable wasn't public, but the thing that threw me off, I did have something similar to this working. Any idea what I did? Just declare e1/2/3 as globals?

Comment: Globals might work, but you'd have to be sure that `pythagentry()` is executed before `pythag()`, which is a fragile solution at best.

Comment: Declaring E1/2/3 as global variables didn't work, neither did moving the runsscored/allowed variables to pythagentry and making them global. I guess I'm going to scour github to see how other people are handling getting entries from previous windows. I may just have to do away with the root window being just buttons, and place the entrys there

Comment: @TylerDodgen Public and Private are not supported concepts in python the same way they are in other languages. There is a convention of putting a single underscore at the start of identifiers you want to operate as somewhat private or maybe similar to "protected" in C++, but it is convention and python itself treats it no differently. Identifiers with two underscores can be used as a stronger suggestion that something is private to a class or the like, and in this case python requires it be referenced outside the class in a special way. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/name-mangling-in-python/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the entry widgets as parameters to the `pythag` function using a lambda in the command callback for the `B4` button.

Also Entry.insert takes 2 parameters, the index and the string, so I made adjustments at the bottom of the `pythag` function as well in the example below.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox

def pythagentry():
    pythaginput = Tk()
    L0 = Label(pythaginput, text= "Expected Wins", fg="black", font = "Times")
    L0.grid(row=1, column=1)
    L1 = Label(pythaginput, text= "Runs Scored", fg="black", font= "Times")
    L1.grid(row=2, column=1)
    L2 = Label(pythaginput, text= "Runs Allowed", fg="black", font= "Times")
    L2.grid(row=3, column=1)
    L3 = Label(pythaginput, text= "Season Length", fg="black", font= "Times")
    L3.grid(row=4, column=1)
    RS = Entry(pythaginput,bd=5)
    RS.grid (row=2, column=2)
    E2 = Entry(pythaginput,bd=5)
    E2.grid (row=3, column=2)
    E3 = Entry(pythaginput,bd=5)
    E3.grid (row=4, column=2)
    B4 = Button (pythaginput,text='Calculate Pythagorean Wins', command = lambda: pythag(RS, E2, E3) )
    B4.grid (row=5, column=2)

def pythag(E1, E2, E3):
    pythagoutput = Tk()
    L4=Label(pythagoutput,text="Expected Wins:",fg="red")
    L4.grid (row =1, column =1)
    E5=Entry(pythagoutput, bd=5)
    E5.grid(row=4,column=1)
    runsscored= float(E1.get())
    runsallowed= float(E2.get())
    lengthseason= float(E3.get())
    ratio = runsscored / runsallowed
    winpct = pow (ratio, 2) / (pow(ratio, 2) + 1)
    expectedwins = lengthseason * winpct
    E5.insert(0, str(expectedwins))
    E5['bg']='grey'

top = Tk()
B1=Button(top, text='Calculate Pythagorean Wins',command = pythagentry,bg="blue")
B1.grid(row=1,column=1)

B2=Button(top, text='Calculate wOBA', bg="Blue")
B2.grid(row=1, column=2)

B3=Button(top, text='Calculate RF/9', bg="blue")
B3.grid(row=2, column=1)

top.mainloop()
```